# Postfix - Transferring NOTIFY command to script using pipe

Tags: postfix, pipe

I have set up system where all mails are piped to my script. In master.cf I have:

```
phptran unix - n n - - pipe flags=DFORq user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/php5 /root/phptran.php ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I can get mail and headers but I cannot get all of RCPT TO command, specifically NOTIFY part, for example in command

```
RCPT TO:user@domain.com NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE
```

How can I get this information from script? Is maybe there a way to put that inside headers?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution but I realy don't like it (too complicated). So if anybody has any other idea I would highly appreciate.

From message header I can get ESMTP ID of message. With message ID I can get content of message in active queue (using postcat -q ).

In postcat result there is named_attribute: notify_flags, which is bitwise or from following values:
never: 1
success: 2
failure: 4
delay: 8